# use parse dashboard login separately

Tags: node.js, parse-platform, parse-server, passport-local, parse-dashboard

I'm using Parse + parse dashboard for several months now. As my parse application have some context outside of parse, dashboard doesn't show that information. Thus I want to have another simple admin panel like app. But also want to avoid doing authentication manually. I just want to use the parse dashboard authentication and do the later things.

Is is possible?

Comment: Any update on this? I am keen.

Comment: Actually I did not find something as well. Later on created an user in parer with admin role and maintaining that. Not a good approach though